# Describe a specific equivalence class

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

Relation on $\mathbb N$:

$x \sim y \iff xy$ is a square

Give a description of the equivalence classes $[3]$, $[9]$, and $[99]$.

I'm not sure what this question is really asking, but this is what I have for $[3]$:

$\{y\in \mathbb N\ |\ 3y \text{ is a square }\}$

Any $y$ of the form $3$ times a square. Is this sufficient?

Comment: Yes. For [3] this is sufficient. But for [9], it is not. What is [1], for example?

Comment: Yes you are correct about equivalence class of $[3]$. Similarly you can write denote other equivalence classes too. $[3]=\{y\in\mathbb{N} | \text{3y is square}\}=\{3,12,...\}$

Answer (score 1):

You can be a little more specific. Ideally, you could give a formula that generates the entire equivalence class.

Using the work you've already done, you know that in order for $3y$ to be a square, all of its prime factors need to be present with even multiplicity. Thus, $y$ needs to contain another factor of $3$ and takes on the form
$$ y = 3z$$
for some $z \in \mathbb{N}$.

Next, for $3(3z) = 9z$ to be a perfect square, $z$ itself must be a perfect square. Thus, $y$ takes on the form $y = 3n^2$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Altogether,
$$ [3] = \{3n^2 \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

In an analogous fashion, you can compute $[9]$ and $[99]$ by doing a prime-factorization on an equivalence class representative.

Comment: So would [9] be any Y of the form 9 times a square? {9,36,81...}

Comment: Not quote! You're missing the perfect squares $1$ and $4$. It would help for you to lay out your thought process more carefully/rigorously/systematically. Start with the fact that $9y$ needs to be a perfect square and take your reasoning from there.